# Grok pattern format

Tags: design-patterns, grok

I would like for my grok to output results based on my custom pattern.
Input: `May 23 22:23:39 vd='root'`

I did a grok discover and the results were:

> %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP} vd=%{QS}

I would like to make a custom pattern that will use the discovered results parameters or conditions.Am having no success this is my custom pattern am new to this grok patterns.

```
#Myown
MYCUSTOM %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP}[ ]%{QUOTEDSTRING}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had just checked your pattern and was ok:
MYCUSTOM %{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:myTime} vd=%{QUOTEDSTRING:myString}

All you need to do was giving grok the field names where you wanted to store the values. I used "myTyme" and "myString" and worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:Timestamp} vd='%{DATA:String}'
```

Maybe this will help